# Parse CSV file by column name with filehelpers

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I'd like to parse a CSV file with the filehelpers DLL.
And I want it to match the column headers with the property names in the class.
I thought that for properties that are not named like the columns I would have to use the "FieldCaption" attribute.
But apparently this is only for writing CSV files?

If I have to arrange the properties in the same manner as in the CSV file and I have to include all columns where is the advantage over just splitting and selecting by number?

Greetings
Patrick

Comment: You need this: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/. No reason to write your own, unless this is for your skills practice.

Answer (score 0):

FileHelpers relies on the concept of a *mapping class* which requires you to specify a field (or autoproperty) for every column, even if you don't need the data in that column. So you might have a mapping class like:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID;

    public string NotImportant1;
    public string NotImportant2;
    public string NotImportant3;

    public string CustomerID;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
    public DateTime OrderDate;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")] // The decimal separator is .
    public decimal Freight;

    [FieldOptional, FieldArrayLength(0, 100)]
    public string[] I_DONT_CARE_WHAT_COMES_AFTER_THIS;
}
```

There is no automatic handling of the unused columns.

> ...where is the advantage over just splitting and selecting by number?

Here are some of the advantages:

- FileHelpers lets you specify any flat file format, not just CSV.
- You can strongly type the fields
- You can provide your own converters to handle how contents map to values
- You can decorate the fields with various attributes to handle the idiosyncracies of your file (quotes, trimming, date formats, etc.)
- The class is also a 'spec' of the file format that your program supports

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I have no control over the CSV file that the application processes, I need it to be robust for changes to the column order or additional fields. Currently if the column order changes because of a new column in between I would have to change the code each time with filehelpers. Though I don't care about additional fields in the first step, I just want the import to run without errors.

Comment: FileHelpers doesn't really cover your use case out of the box. But you could read in the headers (with, say, `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").First()`) and then use the `DelimitedClassBuilder` to [build your class in code](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers.Tests/Tests/Dynamic/DelimitedClassBuilderTests.cs) based on the headers.

Comment: Thanks, I now used the CSVHelper library mentioned in another comment. That works.